# Airplay with photos

Tags: ios, airplay

I looked up the official documents for airplay, found the airplay can only support audio and video. But beside that, the native photos app can airplay photos. So is there any methods to airplay photos? BTW, I know the "mirroring" mode can do this job: I can detect 2 screens in my code and present a different screen to the iOS device's in this mode. However, the "mirroring" mode only exists in iPad 2, new iPad and iPhone 4S...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution here
http://livevision.us/wordpress/2011/02/16/airplay-without-private-api/
and
[How to find the IP-address of the active AirPlay device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101935/how-to-find-the-ip-address-of-the-active-airplay-device)

I could send some UIImage to apple TV.

but I don't know if apple allows using these Unoffical Airplay protocol.

Comment: Thank you! I found another unofficial document for airplay protocol [http://nto.github.com/AirPlay.html](http://nto.github.com/AirPlay.html) serval days ago,  both of them are protocol level, but since they are undocumented, so I am not sure whether apple will reject the app if I use it...

Comment: What happened to your app? Got an approval?

Answer (score 3):

It is documented on Apple's site. When the user enables airplay mirroring, your app will find two UIScreen:s. It's quite simple.

Here's a sample app http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLAirplay/Introduction/Intro.html